# How can i make semantic zoom without list

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a page with different parts, each part is one column, grids in a grid, nothing special... Each part had a header, like "History", "Score" , "comments", and so on. And of course each one looks different to the others.

I'd like to make a semantic zoom, that has the headers in zoomedout view.

I tried to make a ListView from the original page,but got stock when it came to groups.
I cannot set the groups from code ( or plz tell me how), because each group has one item, and they have different look. How can I make grouping from XAML?

Does anything like this one exist?

```
<ListView.Groups>
    <Group Name="History>
       <GroupItem>
          <Grid.../>
       </GroupItem>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="Score"...../>
</ListView.Groups>
```

Am I trying it the wrong way? Which is the right one?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Are those parts of your page dynamic or do you know every one of them in advance?

Comment: thanks for your effort Gabriel, but since its a more than 3 year old question, i"ve probably solved it, and as i remember it was dynamic, but i'm not into XAML and win8 development anymore. cheers

Comment: No problem. Just stumbled upon a similar problem recently and found your question while looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the group data to your ListView in a zoomedoutview using the format below.

```
<SemanticZoom Name="zoom">
  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
<!-- place your normal view here -->
  </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>

  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
<ListView>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <!-- bind group data here -->
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Groupname"/>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
  </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```